# Zipping multiple Files in C++

Tags: c++, windows, linux

I need a zip library (or a function) that can zip\unzip a few files, i tried zlib or gzip I can't find a solution to archive more than one file in a single .zip (or .tar, or .gzip).

Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) could do that.

Comment: @Stefano, I think so.  It's pure C and probably would compile anywhere.  I cannot find any official information about supported platforms though.

Comment: Thank you for help, i solved using minizip. The website says that the library can compile on linux platform (so, in everything :D). Than i made my own wrapper in c++.

Answer (score 1):

zlib can't on it's own, there is [minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) in the contrib dir

Or you can use the newer [zzlib](http://zziplib.sourceforge.net/zzip-file.html) library